# Facebook search API without locale

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, search, locale

I'm playing with the Facebook API. I'm having an issue when I try to search for posts. The problem is that when I search for something, it automatically assumes I set the locale param to en_US. For example, when I search for this I get no results:

http://graph.facebook.com/search?q=tnt.fm/mmci8&type=post

To get results, I have to add the locale attribute and specify a language. This query does get some results:

http://graph.facebook.com/search?q=tnt.fm/mmci8&type=post&locale=pt_BR

I was looking at the Facebook API documentation and I found no answer for my problem. Is there any way to do a "multi-language" search for posts? I mean, do a search and return all results no matter in which language they are.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so.

If you try a different query without specifying the locale e.g., `search?q=obama&type=post` then you'll most likely see some results. Facebook defaults to the locale of the account you are using to search.

A search for `tnt.fm/mmci8` returns no results for me because it is not available in my default `en_US` locale. Your post is only available in the `pt_BR` locale.

It looks like the only options for searching are:

1. Default locale
2. A specified locale